# CupertinoTabBar navigation

Tags: flutter

For the first tabbar: I have a logout button on the DispayMoreScreen. And for Logout button action, app navigates to the root of the app correctly.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/')
```

Tabbar with working Navigation:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
        return new Scaffold(
            bottomNavigationBar: new Material(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: new TabBar(controller: controller, labelColor: Colors.blue[900], tabs: <Tab>[
                  new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.local_shipping, color: Colors.blue[900], size: 30.0), text: 'A'),
                  new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.insert_drive_file, color: Colors.blue[900], size: 30.0), text: 'B'),
                  new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.more_horiz, color: Colors.blue[900], size: 30.0), text: 'C'),
                ])),
            body: new TabBarView(controller: controller, children: <Widget>[
              new ShipmentScreen.ShipmentTab(),
              new InvoiceScreen.InvoiceTab(),
              new DisplayMoreScreen.MoreTab(),
            ])
        );
  }
```

But when I implement CupertinoTabBar, after logout app stays on the same screen.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: new CupertinoTabBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        activeColor: Colors.blue[900],
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.local_shipping),
            title: new Text("A")
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.insert_drive_file),
            title: new Text("B")
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
            title: new Text("C")
          )
        ]
      ),
      tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new CupertinoTabView(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            switch(index) {
              case 0:
                return new ShipmentScreen.ShipmentTab();
              case 1:
                return new InvoiceScreen.InvoiceTab();
              case 2:
                return new DisplayMoreScreen.MoreTab();
            }
          },
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to setState() when you’re tapping on the tabs:

“This [StatelessWidget] doesn't store the active tab itself. You must listen to the [onTap] callbacks and call `setState` with a new [currentIndex] for the new selection to reflect.”

I also think that your “switch (index)” in the builder should instead switch to a “currentIndex” variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a globalKey to make it work.

Check out this [solution](https://medium.com/flutter-community/add-a-tab-bar-and-navigation-bar-with-ios-style-in-your-next-flutter-app-bf97b1e27e3a)